# Swift: Remove Generic item in LinkedList

Tags: swift, generics, linked-list

I'm trying to remove a generic item from a linked list. The problem I'm having is that when I'm checking `head?.value == value`, it requires "T" to conform to Equatable.

I'm having trouble making that work. When I try to make `NNode<T>` Equatable by adding the Equatable to my generic class `NNode<T: Equatable>`, my typealias `Node` has an error of not conforming to protocol Equatable. What do I do?

```
class NNode<T: Equatable> {
    var value: T
    var next: NNode?

    init(value: T, next: NNode?) {
       self.value = value
       self.next = next
     }
  }

class LinkedList<T> {
public typealias Node = NNode<T>

func delete(value: T) {
    if head?.value == value {
        head = head?.next
    }

    var prev: Node?
    var current = head

    while current != nil && current?.value != value {
        prev = current
        current = current?.next
    }

    prev?.next = current?.next
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to conform `T` to `Equatable` in the `LinkedList` as well:

```
class NNode<T: Equatable> { ... }

class LinkedList<T: Equatable> { 
    public typealias Node = NNode<T>
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! i was stuck on this for awhile